# React only binds Component methods to this - work around?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to avoid the boilerplate when using ES6 with react 0.14?

Until now I didn't have to worry about my function to be bound to the `Component` I created but that is no longer (why?!?) the case and the Component is only bounded to the `Component` super class (If I understood the errors correctly).

So what I really need to do each time I create a new class is to add this code to the constructor:

```
class CustomComp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.newFunction = this.newFunction.bind(this);
  }

  newFunction(){
    console.log('This is user defined function');

}
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.newFunction}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

So if I wont bind `newFunction` it will fail (no props, state or anything).

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136#.fd5z0vmjl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding):

> **No Autobinding**
>
> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that
>   they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to
>   explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>.

So, no there is not an automatic way to bind all methods that is new in 0.14.  But, as the documentation suggests, you can:

**1) use arrow functions** (However, if you are using Babel, you need stage 0)**:**

```
class CustomComp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  newFunction = () => {
    console.log('This is user defined function');

}
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.newFunction}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

**2) you can bind *in place*:**

```
class CustomComp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  newFunction() {
    console.log('This is user defined function');

}
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.newFunction.bind(this)}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

**3) you can use an arrow function *in place* (which is like a bind):**

```
class CustomComp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  newFunction() {
    console.log('This is user defined function');

}
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.newFunction()}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

I tend to use number 2 & 3 if I only have a 1-2 methods.  Number 1 is good, but you have to remember the syntax for every method definition.  If I have a lot of methods, I do tend to bind in the constructor.

Comment: Great answer. Just a little hint: you skip the extra set of `{}` and just write `onClick={() => this.newFunction()}`.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.